# Mix post date with post meta value using WP_Query

Tags: posts, wp-query, meta-query

Finding any way to push old posts into the WP_Query using custom fields.
For example I have 10 posts in this year, and want to republish 2 posts from the past to custom rss feed.

So the posts must be ordered by post date and value in the post meta for old posts:

```
new post - (post date: 2018-11-11)
new post - (post date: 2018-11-10)
old post - (post date: 2017-05-01, post-meta date: 2018-11-09)
new post - (post date: 2018-11-08)
```

I try to order by 2 values in WP_Query but it is not working

```
<?php
   add_filter('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
        if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_feed()) {
            $query->set('posts_per_rss', 3);
            $query->set('post_type', 'post');
            $query->set('post_status', 'publish');

            $query->set('meta_query', [
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'push_clause' => [
                    'key' => 'is-push',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                ],
                'exclude_clause' => [
                    'key' => 'is-exclude',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ]
            ]);

            $query->set('orderby', ['push_clause' => 'DESC']);
        }
    });
```

Is there any way to implement this using WP_Query?

**Update**:
I've written pure sql query, working sorting as I want

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_date, m.*, IFNULL(m.meta_value, wp_posts.post_date) as d
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (wp_posts.ID = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'is-push')
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
ORDER BY 
     d DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've decided to use custom sql query with get_results method.

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*, IFNULL(m2.meta_value, p.post_date_gmt) as zen_date
            FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} m1 ON (p.ID = m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key = 'is-exclude')
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} m2 ON (p.ID = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = 'is-push')
            WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND m1.post_id IS NULL
            GROUP BY p.ID ORDER BY zen_date DESC LIMIT 0, 50";

$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

foreach($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);

    // do something
}
```

If somebody suggests something better, I'll be glad to accept that answer.